# UK Ancestral visa - dependents: which visa type my I select

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, dependent-visa, ancestry

I am South African and want to apply for my UK Ancestry visa. I have filled in the forms, paid all the money and am waiting to go for my appointment.

This morning I applied for my 3 children but I used the incorrect visa type. And lots of tears and drama I have managed to click the refund button (it was not working) it will take 28 days to get my R90 000 back.

Now I am trying to get the right visa type. I would like to submit all our applications in on the same day. IS THIS POSSIBLE?

We called the UK visa number it cost GBP10, a chinese person answered and told us to read the website, then put us on hold. I also drove to my nearest visa center and managed to get someone to talk to me. She said I must choose "ancestry-child" but this does not exist on the website.

I see another question answered saying you must select "work - no tier - dependants more than 6 months" I have started another application but near the end it asks for the sponsors UK status (british citizen. EEA national. permanent resident. temporary resident) what must I write if my ancestral visa has not been approved yet?

Answer (score 1):

> what must I write if my ancestral visa has not been approved yet?

I would write "Ancestry visa applicant" and include the application number, if it is available.